# I am unable to navigate to a url that I have stored in a variable

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

```
string file = "c:\file.txt";

Process.Start(@"c:\script\call\other.exe");
Sleep();
Process.Start(@"c:\script\call\disconnect.exe");

string url = File.ReadAllText(file);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

Here's what I'm trying to do. The first script (AutoIT) is interacting with a desktop app that causes a Firefox window to launch. I cannot use the driver to interact with an existing browser session, so the second script is copying the url from that window and pasting to a `.txt` file. The program keeps failing when trying to read the file, `Illegal characters in path`. I've done some research and it seems it has something to do with encoding. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try adding the `@` at the front of your `file` value. You have it on both `Process.Start` statements but not your very first line.

Comment: You're escaping the f character, which according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa691087(v=VS.71).aspx) is a "form feed" character. Not sure what it means, but I'd be willing to bet it's not helping. Edit: [Form Feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed) as defined by wikipedia. So yea, that's gotta be screwing it up.

Comment: are you using `FirefoxProfile `?

Comment: @FahadJameel, no I am not.

Comment: what is the driver you are using?

Comment: I am using     IWebDriver.

Comment: can you put the code of the declaration of the driver variable.

Comment: IWebDriver driver; Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @sab669, thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, and it did not work. Returned the same error.

Comment: try escaping the back slashes `"c:\file.txt"` becomes `c:\\file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I have seen `drivers` would be declared something like this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

(or other browser driver).

Also, I know in `FirefoxDriver()` you must include a `http://` at the beginning of the URL. Maybe your issue is similar.

To make it work for file path you can do:

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(@'c:\file.txt');
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary);
```

Comment: This is worth a shot, but without knowing the value(s) in the file we can't say for sure. OP did mention that the application fails "when trying to read the file", though, so I don't think it's necessarily an issue with the driver though. Sounds like it's not even getting to `GoToUrl`

Comment: This is what is being stored in the .txt file (some parts are dynamic because it's passing info to a webapp, but it will always be structured like this:  "http: //10.54.97.36/Pop/Default.aspx?&gtxt=&crm=http%3a%2f%2fsite.domain.com%2fwebapp%2fproperty.aspx%3fCalliD%3d100298530520150828%26CCPhoneNumber%3d86975612%26ANI%3d%2b13654795126&pn=Test&lang=en-US&etxt="

Comment: I know that formatting is bad, I'm not sure how to use the site just yet.

Comment: He's not trying to open the text file with the browser driver, he's trying to open the file to pull the URL out of it and then pass it to the browser driver.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `@` in front of the path to the text file because it is not escaped properly.

```
string file = @"c:\file.txt";
string url = File.ReadAllText(file);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

That should allow you to read the file.